# Study of super-Gaussian or super-Exponential distributions?

Tags: probability, statistics, concentration-of-measure

the terms may be weird, but they just mean distributions with heavier tail with Gaussian/exponential respectively, in a way that is exactly the opposite of sub-Gaussian and sub-exponential.

There's apparently a lot of study on sub-Gaussian and sub-exponential distributions, but I wonder if there's any on super-Gaussian and super-exponential distributions?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a ton. Just google "power law distribution" (look in fields like statistical physics, econ/finance, network science, research with the word 'complexity' in it.)

Comment: Or try *heavy tailed distribution* or *fat tailed distribution* or *leptokurtic*

Comment: I'm confused by your terms and the responses received so far. If, as you say, a super-exponential is the opposite of a subexponential distribution, doesn't this make it a "light" distribution such as in the Weibull class?